# Dual Number Problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am wondering what the value of

$$ \epsilon ^2 \over \epsilon$$

should be in the dual number space. This is a straightforward question to ask with complex numbers, but in this case, I'm coming up with two possibilities. Firstly, since $\epsilon^2 = 0$ this expression should equal zero.

But if I use the decomposition:

$${\epsilon \epsilon \over \epsilon }= \epsilon$$

So which is it? Can you give me any reason why either of these reasons don't work?

Comment: What makes you think division by $\epsilon$ is defined?  Why should the quotient exist at all?

Comment: I'm looking at this from the perspective of automatic differentiation. The quotient ${a + \epsilon b \over c +\epsilon d}$ is defined from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number). But I can see that if c=0 this would cause a division by zero. Which I should have looked at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space of dual numbers is $\mathbb{C}[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$. The element $\epsilon$ is *not* invertible in this ring (because it is nilpotent), so any expression involving $\epsilon^{-1}$ makes no sense.

Comment: But you can divide a dual number by another dual number right? So $a+\epsilon b \over x + \epsilon y$ is defined, so long as x is non-zero.

Comment: The dual numbers *do not* form a field, because they contain nilpotent elements. The element $\epsilon$ is not invertible, and in fact it is not of the form $x + \epsilon b$ with $x$ complex number $\neq 0$.